# User credentials seen in header form data even after using https

Tags: javascript, php, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Passing user credential from Angular to PHP, they are totally visible in developer tools >  Network > Headers > Form data, see below image:

I am using Https everywhere but still my credentials are seen in plain text.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: It is encrypted after it leaves the browser.

Comment: but i dont want it to be seen here, any suggestions

Comment: What is the purpose of your need?

Comment: Why not? The data displayed there already is exposed to the user via the `console` pane. If you are using `hidden` input's they can be accessed/viewed. All other data points come from user input anyway. The purpose of SSL is to secure the data between the browser and the server. When the server reads the encrypted data it decrypts it and gives the plain text value to the application.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 ways to "hide" parameters from appearing in the developers tools:

### 1st (weakest) encode it

Depending on the algorithm, the data is unreadable afterwards but can easily be decoded to the plaintext

### 2st Hash the data

The data is unreadable afterwards but you cannot read it yourself too.

### 3rd Encrypt data

Requires passwords / keys to be sent, leaving you with a dilemma.

### 4th and probably strongest: Don't send the data at all

Store the secret on the server and link it to the public session id.

Comment: can you please refer me on a link for 2nd , i dont understand 4th, If my username and password is seen in header and passes to php, then people can call the php from postman passing the user /pass and secret will be returned in response

Comment: @user2828442 yes, that's why you should avoid this at all and hide the credentials on the server, giving only a token to the user. concerning hashing: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: when i am passing from angular to php then its seen in browser, i dont need a solution at php side, i hope i am able to clarify myself